# Test python code in a submodule with Github actions

Tags: python, github, testing

I have a python module I need to share with others, so we moved it to a git submodule. Using the module works fine by importing `from my_submodule.my_module import MyClass` in both the submodule and supermodule. I can even test the submodule only with `python -m pytest` from the submodule directory, or test both the submodule and supermodule from the supermodule directory.

In Github I have an action to run `pytest`, but the tests fail every time with an import error claiming not to be able to find the submodule. If I change the import statements in the submodule to `from my_module import MyClass` (instead of `from my_submodule.my_module import MyClass`) the tests run fine. However, then the supermodule can't find the module `my_module`.

I have a `conftest.py` file in the supermodule and the submodule for module-specific testing configuration.

So my question is: **how can I test both the supermodule and submodule with Github actions, while still being able to use the submodule in the supermodule?**

---

To reproduce locally:

1. `git clone git@github.com:$GIT_USERNAME/my_supermodule.git sup_mod --recurse-submodules`
2. `git clone git@github.com:$GIT_USERNAME/my_submodule.git sub_mod`
3. `python3.8 -m venv my_venv`
4. `source my_venv/bin/activate`
5. `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
6. `python -m pip install --upgrade pytest`
7. a) `cd sup_mod/my_submodule` b) `cd sub_mod`
8. `git checkout main`
9. `python -m pytest`

Step 8 should pass/fail depending on whether you performed step 7a or 7b.

```sh
$ tree -aI 'venv|*cache*|*git|.gitmodules'
.
├── conftest.py
├── .github
│   └── workflows
│       └── pytest.yml
├── my_submodule
│   ├── conftest.py
│   ├── .github
│   │   └── workflows
│   │       └── pytest.yml
│   ├── my_module.py
│   ├── README.md
│   └── tests
│       └── test_my_module.py
├── README.md
├── tests
│   └── test_top.py
└── top_module.py

7 directories, 10 files
```

```py
#top_class.py
class TopClass:
    def __init__(self): self.my_class = MyClass()
    def bar(self): return self.my_class.foo()
```

```py
#tests/test_top.py
from top_module import TopClass
def test_topclass(): assert TopClass().bar()
```

```py
#my_submodule/my_module.py
class MyClass:
    def foo(self):
        return True
```

```py
#my_submodule/tests/test_my_module.py 
from my_submodule.my_module import MyClass
def test_myclass(): assert MyClass().foo()
```

```yaml
#.github/wokflows/pytest.yml
name: Pytest
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install pytest
    - name: Perform tests with pytest
      run: |
        python -m pytest
```

Comment: I think a part of the problem is that the cloned repo folder name is different from the `my_submodule` name. Github actions fail no matter what I name the folder locally